# MarkerWithLabel labelContent div onclick event

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a marker containing several DIV's and I want to be able to access click events on the individual DIV's and not only the whole marker.

This is my marker:

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: myMap.getCenter(),
  map: myMap,
  opacity: 0.0,
  labelContent: "<div id=container>" +
  " <div id=largeDiv" +
  "></div>" +
  " <div id=smallDiv" +
  "></div>" +
  "</div>",
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(width/2, height/2),
  labelClass: "labelClass" // the CSS class for the label
});
```

And these are three solutions I have tried in order to register click events on "largeDiv"

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Works but too early, has no effect
  alert("Solution 1");
  $("#largeDiv").on("click", function() {
  alert("clicked largeDiv");
  });
});
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) { // Does not work
  if (e.target.id == "largeDiv") {
    alert("Solution 2");
    $("#largeDiv").on("click", function() {
      alert("clicked largeDiv");
    });
  }
});
setTimeout(function() { // Works
  alert("Solution 3");
  $("#largeDiv").on("click", function() {
      alert("clicked largeDiv");
  });
}, 1000);
```

The third solution is obviously a terrible solution, I would much rather add the click listener as soon as the DIV had been created. How would I best accomplish this?

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/lantchips/pen/QyOEZO)

Answer (score 1):

```
//it works

var div = document.createElement('div'),
    textElem = document.createTextNode('label');
div.appendChild(textElem);
$(div).on("click", function () {
  alert("click");
});

var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: myMap.getCenter(),
  map: myMap,
  opacity: 0.0,
  labelContent: div,
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(width/2, height/2),
  labelClass: "labelClass" // the CSS class for the label
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the div as an jQuery HTML element before adding it to your marker.  Add the event listener to it at the same time. e.g. I think this should work:

```
var yourDiv = $("<div id=container>" +
  " <div id=largeDiv" +
  "></div>" +
  " <div id=smallDiv" +
  "></div>" +
  "</div>");

yourDiv.on("click", function() {
  alert("clicked largeDiv");
});

var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: myMap.getCenter(),
  map: myMap,
  opacity: 0.0,
  labelContent: yourDiv,
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(width/2, height/2),
  labelClass: "labelClass" // the CSS class for the label
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It seems I can't reference it that way in labelContent, it only works when I set labelContent: yourDiv.html(), but I assume that only makes a copy of it.